# Connecting Azure public services from on-premise

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

How does network traffic flow from on-premise to the Azure public service if there's a site-to-site VPN-tunnel between Azure and on-premise?

Does the VPN-connection route traffic only to VNET? What if there's a service that does not reside in the VNET? Does the traffic still enter the VPN-tunnel or it goes straight to public network from the on-premise?

Sorry if this is a bit vague question, but I'm trying to understand how the traffic flows from on-prem to Azure Storage/Azure SQL Database/Azure Data Factory/other public services

Comment: Do you have any questions in the reply?

Comment: Thanks this helped! So basically S2S VPN will only route traffic between onprem network and Azure Virtual Network. Public services are reached through the public internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [what is VPN gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpngateways),

> A VPN gateway is a specific type of virtual network gateway that is
>   used to send encrypted traffic between an Azure virtual network and an
>   on-premises location over the public Internet.

you will see that VPN-connection route traffic only to VNETs. A Site-to-Site VPN gateway connection is used to connect your on-premises network to an **Azure virtual network** over an IPsec/IKE (IKEv1 or IKEv2) VPN tunnel.

Generally, without any reverse proxy, traffic flows from on-prem to Azure Storage/Azure SQL Database/Azure Data Factory/other public services that do not reside in the VNET, will be directly routed with a public DNS name or IP address of those services.

Especially, a preview feature [Private Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/index) allows you to connect to various PaaS services in Azure via a private endpoint. With Private Link, customers can enable cross-premises access to the private endpoint using ExpressRoute, private peering, or VPN tunneling. Read [Using cases of Private Link for Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview#use-cases-of-private-link-for-azure-sql-database) and [Using Private Endpoints for Azure Storage (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints)

Hope this helps.

Comment: These seems only possible for azure serviced. No on prem